# WAFInvalidParameterException

Tags: python-3.x, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-waf

I call the boto3 waf-regional api as following code:

```
response = client.update_web_acl(
    WebACLId=acl_id,
    ChangeToken=get_token(),
    Updates=[
        {
            'Action': 'INSERT',
            'ActivatedRule': {
                'Priority': 123,
                'RuleId': rule_id,
                'Action': {
                    'Type': 'BLOCK'
                },
                'OverrideAction': {
                    'Type': 'NONE'
                },
                'Type': 'REGULAR'
            }
        },
    ],
    DefaultAction={
        'Type': 'ALLOW'
    }
)
```

But it keeps giving me the error that `botocore.errorfactory.WAFInvalidParameterException: An error occurred (WAFInvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateWebACL operation:`

What can be the reason for that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figure this out. The point is that in a function call, you either use ActivatedRule|OverrideAction to add a rule group, or you use ActivatedRule|Action in other cases. More information is here in the aws documentation:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/waf.html#WAF.Client.update_web_acl